# Why is cakephp throwing a database error?

Tags: database, cakephp, model

When I'm trying to insert a new invoice into the database, cakephp is throwing an error saying that it can't find the column relationship.partytwo in the where clause. What I'm trying to achieve is making sure that the user sending the invoice has an active relationship in the relationships_users database with the person receiving the invoice before the invoice is sent, sadly all I'm getting is the database error.

here is the structure of my tables

```
invoices - id, to, biller, subject, description, datecreated, duedate
relationships_users - id, partyone, partytwo, expirydate,active
```

here is the Relationship model

```
  <?php

class Relationship extends AppModel
{

    var $name = 'Relationship';
    public $useTable = 'relationships_users';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Invoice' =>
            array(
                'className'              => 'Invoice',
                'joinTable'              => 'invoice',
                'foreignKey'             => 'invoice_id'));
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' =>array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' =>'partyone','partytwo',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'username',
            )); 

    var $validate = array(
        'date' => array(
            'rule' => array(
                'datevalidation',
                'systemDate'
            ),
            'message' => 'Current Date and System Date is mismatched'
        ),
        'partytwo' => array(
            'userExists' => array(
                'rule' => array(
                    'userExists',
                ),
                'message' => 'That username doesnt exist.'
            ),
        ),
    );

    function datevalidation($field = array(), $compare_field = null)
    {
        if ($field['date'] > $compare_field)
            return TRUE;
        else
            return FALSE;
    }

    function userExists($check)
    {   
        $userExists = $this->User->find('count', array('conditions' => array('User.username'=>$check)));
        if ($userExists == 1) {
           return TRUE;
        }
        else
            return FALSE;
    }

}
```

here is my invoice model

```
   <?php
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class Invoice extends AppModel{ 
        var $name='Invoice'; 
        public $useTable = 'invoices';
        public $primaryKey = 'id';
        public $hasMany = array(
        'Relationship' =>array(
            'className' => 'Relationship',
            'foreignKey' =>'relationship_id',
        )); 
        var $validate = array(
            'to' => array(
                'relationshipExists' => array(
                    'rule' => array(
                        'relationshipExists',
                        ),
                    'message' => 'sorry you dont have a relationship with that user.'
                    ),
                ),
            );


        public function relationshipExists($check){ 
            if($this->hasAny(array('Relationship.partytwo'=>current($check))))
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

    }
```

here is my addinvoice function

```
public function addinvoice(){
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Create Invoice');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.jpg');   
    $this->layout='home_layout';

    if($this->request->is('post')){
        pr($this->Invoice->set($this->request->data));
        if($this->Invoice->validates(array('fieldList'=>array('to','Invoice.relationshipExists')))){
        //  $this->Relationship->create();
            $this->Invoice->save($this->request->data); 
            $this->Session->setFlash('The invoice has been saved');  
      }}else { 
                $this->Session->setFlash('The invoice could not be saved. Please, try again.');
             }
    }
```

Comment: There isn't a `partytwo` field in your `Invoices` table, that would be why you're getting the error. You're also stating that a `Relationship hasMany Relationship`, which is only going to cause problems. I'd perosnally rethink your model relationships, you've definitely complicated them a lot more than you need to.

Comment: fixed that up but its still throwing the same database error

Answer (score 0):

A `hasMany` foreign key is supposed to be in *the other* table. If `Relationship` *hasMany* `Invoices`, the `Invoices` must have the foreign key `relationship_id`.

Seems what you want to model is a `belongsTo`, in which a `Relationship` *belongsTo* an `Invoice`, which means the foreign key is in the `Relationship` model/table.

Comment: it doesn't like having 2 belongTo